# Link to App-Store Webpage Without App Redirect

Tags: ios-appstore, mobile-safari

I have an app in the app store and I'm trying to link to it on my webpage.  I've got the link working on any standard browser, but when I open the website in WeChat and use the link, it does nothing.  This problem is not occuring on my Android device, only on iOS.  So I think what's happening is iOS thinks that the link is an ad and won't allow the page to open the app store.

I've tried just plain old http://itunes.com/apps/appname, but this seems to attempt a redirect as well.

So is there a way to link a user to the app store without opening the app-store app?

Comment: Are you using marketing links? What's the web source of your web page (or post a link to the page you have live now). Also - what versions of iOS safari do are you targeting (and can your page deliver different link content/css to different browsers)? There are so many marketing options listed at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ it's hard to know which of the many you might use for better effect than a simple link.

Comment: http://tototalsaving.com is the website and the links only show up on a mobile device.  I'm not sure how to target different versions of safari, I've tried looking something like that up, but have been unable to find anything.

Comment: Cool - red and gold and savings! I wonder how many people you lose by requiting an email before showing the download link, though...

Comment: Are you viewing it on mobile?  They're just in a media-query - I'm no cyber nazi.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer smart app banners for the best mobile safari experience.

Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Basically you insert code in the header area:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Comment: The problem is that this is opening inside WeChat's browser.  Would clicking this banner send them to the app store or through the browser?

Comment: @Csteele5 Good luck using web view in WeChat. Your banner renders on iOS 9 but not on iOS 8.4 for me, but the sites are slow to render at the moment. I'd put the download link on all safari / desktop or not, but that's your call. The URL should get intercepted by mobile safari and dump the user into the App Store app on iOS (and that's what I'm seeing)

Comment: Right, but in the WeChat browser it pretty much blocks any attempts to go to iTunes or the app store. I wonder if it thinks it's an ad or something. Have you had problems using WeChat Web view before?